# UITableView WillDisplayCell Method call after particular time?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I am trying to put animation on UITableViewCell bottom to top which working fine code for that:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(audioVcCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{


cell.alpha =0.0;

    UIView *cellContentView = [cell contentView];
    CGFloat rotationAngleDegrees = -30;
    CGFloat rotationAngleRadians = rotationAngleDegrees * (M_PI/180);
    CGPoint offsetPositioning = CGPointMake(0, cell.contentView.frame.size.height*4);
    CATransform3D transform = CATransform3DIdentity;
    transform = CATransform3DRotate(transform, rotationAngleRadians, -50.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    transform = CATransform3DTranslate(transform, offsetPositioning.x, offsetPositioning.y, -50.0);
    cellContentView.layer.transform = transform;
    cellContentView.layer.opacity = 0.8;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:3.0 delay:indexPath.row+3 usingSpringWithDamping:0.85 initialSpringVelocity:0.8 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
        cellContentView.layer.transform = CATransform3DIdentity;
        cellContentView.layer.opacity = 1;
        cell.alpha=1.0;

    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

    }];
```

}

Here I want to display each cell one by one with gap of 2 or 3 seconds. Currently Cell will display quickly. Thanks in advance.

Comment: change the delay `delay:3`

Comment: if i change it will show all cell at the same time not one by one thats why i put here indexPath.row

Comment: try this. Write the UIView animateDuration Code in "dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 15.0 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^(void){
            
       
            
        });"

Comment: @PhaniRaghu it will display cell randomly  not by index  like 0,1,2...

Comment: First tell me one thing. Is it takes time to display the cell?

Comment: yup it is taking time.

Comment: Then Change DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND‌ to DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH

Comment: sorry same issue..

Comment: will you post the changed code again?

Comment: i changed dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, indexPath.row * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{}) and it works fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by the idea given by @PhaniRaghu I made some changes in his answer and it worked fine.

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, indexPath.row * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:3.0 
            delay:indexPath.row 
            usingSpringWithDamping:0.85 
            initialSpringVelocity:0.8 
            options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut 
            animations:^{
                cellContentView.layer.transform = CATransform3DIdentity;
                cellContentView.layer.opacity = 1;
                cell.alpha=1.0;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    }];
});
```